# Finding words within an Array

Tags: swift

How to check if any of words of a string exist in an array?

For example:

```
let arr = ["This", "is", "Array", "of", "String"]
let str = "The word String is exists"
```

The result should be:

> Found words: "String", "is"

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a less naive solution that will work for strings that contain punctuation.

This first splits the string into words using localized rules. It then finds the intersection of the two arrays of words.

```
func findWords(text: String, words: [String]) -> [String] {
    var textWords: Set<String> = []
    text.enumerateSubstrings(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, options: [.byWords, .localized]) { (word, _, _, _) in
        if let word = word {
            textWords.insert(word)
        }
    }

    let matches = textWords.intersection(words)

    return Array(matches)
}

print(findWords(text: "The word String is exists", words: ["This", "is", "Array", "of", "String"]))
print(findWords(text: "Hello there. How are you today?", words: ["there", "is", "today"]))
```

Output:

> ["String", "is"]
>   ["there", "today"]

As of this writing, none of the other solutions will work for the second example.

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = ["This", "is", "Array", "of", "String"]
let str = "The word String is exists"
let set1 = Set(str.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).filter { !$0.isEmpty })
let set2 = Set(arr)
let result = set1.intersection(set2)
print(result)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't work if the string contains any punctuation other than spaces.

Comment: You now support other whitespace besides a simple space, but it doesn't handle any other punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let str = "The word String is exists"
let all = str.components(separatedBy:" ")
let arr = ["This", "is", "Array", "of", "String"]
let res =  arr.filter { all.contains($0) } // or contains(where
```

Comment: I would just promote `arr` to a `Set` if it gets big enough, to avoid quadratic time complexity.

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't work if the string contains any punctuation other than spaces.

Comment: @Alexander yes but since it'a already suggested no need to repeat

Comment: @rmaddy we may work on the current values , op should be careful in such cases

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
var resArray = [String]()
let wordArr = str.components(separatedBy: " ")
for s in wordArr {
     if arr.contains(s) {
       resArray.append(s)
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) you can simplify this code into just a simple `filter` statement, 2) you should use a `Set` for `resArray` (what does "res array" even mean)? 3) Don't reward questions that don't show any effort. For all you know, you just did this guy's homework without having him learn anything at all

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't work if the string contains any punctuation other than spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the result directly with a set intersection:

```
let arr = ["This", "is", "Array", "of", "String"]
let str = "The word String is exists"
let separators = CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted
let result     = Set(arr).intersection(str.components(separatedBy: separators))
```